# mail.app import error fails - home folder full

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mail.app, memory, import

I was getting an error in Mail.app that the home folder is full. Yet the volume has 256G 
of space. I've done this [support process from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA24486?locale=en_US). Now I get a failure during import. I'm importing 250K of messages.

I just realized the drive has 44G free, but 251G available. I'm going to delete some photo cache.

Does the index have a limit?

Can a folder have a limit less than the entire drive?

I've run CleamMyMac and deleted caches, trash, etc.

```
______________________________________
Here is some of the info from EtreCheck

Hardware Information:
    iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010) - Vintage!
    iMac Model: iMac11,2
    3.06 GHz Intel Core i3 (i3) CPU: 2-core
    16 GB RAM - At maximum
        BANK 0/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR3 1333 
        BANK 1/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR3 1333 
        BANK 0/DIMM1 - 4 GB DDR3 1333 
        BANK 1/DIMM1 - 4 GB DDR3 1333 
Drives:
    disk0 - SAMSUNG HD502HJ 500.11 GB (Mechanical - 7200 RPM)
    Internal SATA 3 Gigabit Serial ATA
        disk0s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
        disk0s2 - N**********1 (Journaled HFS+) 499.25 GB (454.48 GB used)
        disk0s3 - Recovery HD (Mac OS Extended) [Recovery] 650 MB

Mounted Volumes:
    disk0s2 - N**********1
        499.25 GB (454.48 GB used, 261.60 GB available, 44.51 GB free)
        Journaled HFS+
        Mount point: /
```

Comment: Is that 250K messages or just 250KB (kilobytes) of messages.   If the former, how much storage space is that ~250,000 messages taking up?